# How to prevent page from reload using selenium web driver or using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Below options are not working.
Are there any other options to try with in selenium c# or using JavaScript?

Tried with below statements but still no luck.
`driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("Keys.ESCAPE");`
and 
`driver.execute_script("window.stop();")`

`driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("Keys.ESCAPE");`
and 
`driver.execute_script("window.stop();")`

Want to stop reload of a web page.

Answer (score 3):

### stop()

The [Window `stop()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_stop.asp) stops window loading and is the same as clicking on the browser's stop button.

---

### Example Usage

- *Python*:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.stop();");
  ```
- *Java*:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.stop();");
  ```
- *C#*:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
  ```

> **Note**: Because of the script execution, this method cannot interrupt its parent document's loading, but it will stop its images, new windows, and other still-loading objects.